# Why does Octave allow renaming of functions?

Tags: octave, gnu

If I open Octave and do:

```
a = 1:10;
sum(a)

ans = 55
```

But if I then do:

```
sum = 30;
sum(a)
```

I get an error:

```
error: A(I): index out of bounds; value 10 out of bound 1
```

Octave has allowed me to change where the word "sum" points so now it's at a value not a function. Why is this allowed and shouldn't I be given a warning - is this not incredibly dangerous?

How, if I realise I've done this, do I remove the reference without closing octave and losing my workspace?

Comment: Matlab does it this way.... You can even do `min = @max; min ([2 3 4 5])` which will now output `ans = 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine Octave does not allow variables to have the same as a function. You write a program in Octave and you have a variable named `total` which is not a function. Everything is fine. A new Octave version comes out and adds a function named `total`. Your program would stop working and you would have to rename your variables. That level of backwards incompatibility would be worse.  And the issue wouldn't be limited to new Octave versions.  Maybe you later decide that you want to use an Octave package which brings a whole set of new functions, one of which could clash with your variables.

However, in the upcoming release of Octave, out of bounds errors will give a hint that the variable name is shadowing a function.  In Octave 4.2.1:

```
octave-cli-4.2.0:1> a = 1:10;
octave-cli-4.2.0:2> sum = 30;
octave-cli-4.2.0:3> sum (a)
error: sum(10): out of bound 1
```

While in in 4.3.0+ (which one day will become 4.4):

```
octave-cli-4.3.0+:1> a = 1:10;
octave-cli-4.3.0+:2> sum = 30;
octave-cli-4.3.0+:3> sum(a)
error: sum(10): out of bound 1 (note: variable 'sum' shadows function)
```

---

However, the real problem is not that variables can shadow functions. The real problem is that the syntax does not allow to distinguish between a variable and a function.  Both variable indexing and function calling uses the same brackets `()` (other languages typically use `()` for functions and `[]` for index variables).  And even if you call a function without any arguments, the parentheses are optional:

```
foo(1)  # 1st element of foo?  Or is foo a function?
foo     # Is this a variable or a function call without any arguments?
foo()   # idem
```

This syntax is mainly required for Matlab compatibility which is one of the aims of GNU Octave.

To work around this deficiency, Octave coding guidelines (guidelines required for code contributed to Octave. The Octave parser does not really care) requires functions to always use parentheses and to have a space between them and the function name:

```
foo (x, y); # there is a space after foo so it must be a function
foo(x, y);  # there is no space, it is indexing a matrix
foo         # this is a variable
foo ();     # this is a function
```

Comment: Interesting rationalization in 1st paragraph. Interesting coding style info at the end. I understand you want to explain why the error message is "Index out of bounds" instead of "Attempt to call something not a function". You may want to reconsider the deprecatory vocabulary ("problem", "deficiency") used to describe the underlying language property. IMO it lessens the value of your answer.

Comment: I think being an Octave developer gives me enough leeway to use whatever vocabulary I want against it.

Answer (score 3):

> How, if I realise I've done this, do I remove the reference without closing octave and losing my workspace?

Use the command `clear sum` to clear the user definition of symbol `sum`, which will revert it to the built-in meaning. (That is, the built-in definition will no longer be shadowed by user definition.)

As for why Octave works this way, one would have to ask the maintainers of this open-source project. Perhaps it's because Matlab works this way, and Octave strives to be as compatible as possible.